# optinal function in interface gives Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' when inside a condition

Tags: typescript

I cannot removed an error even when I wrap it in a condition :

I have this in my interface :
[image]

and then in my code I do this :
[image]

I also have a condition to make sure this.customType exist

and that red line says :
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

How is this possible if I make sure it exist in a if right before?

I've made a typescript code here, apparently it's because I'm using a variable. anyway around this?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQFcBnGCAW3wiXQQHNi4BvAKDjgG0BrYATwC44pKMjoBdQa3bsAbpgA2CACaZUAfgAU6eZjqDMSXgEpBAIwgR5wAwG42cAL52HLFtmqk42EmUrVaDIJEpBRUNPSMALzMLBwA5KYGBsBxEjHScHKKKqgaxEbpGXBQwDCEUEhCdhkOADRsLi5uHvDeIeQAKrxgwPgAFhbEwJXRCUlIKa4sCOhwGm2+YQHE8YlIyakAdFnKqsAFUtILof4Rq+MpYtsKu7lx8pZxRs5T0+jzPhRdPf2Dw3AAMgBXk+fnCDAO9hmc2OYOWHFh316AwgQyQVx2OX2hQysKWZ0R3WRf3R12yew090ez3sjSAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition, try writing it as:

```js
if (customConfigs?.[this.customType]?.validate) {
```

I'd suspect the error is on the possibility of either `customConfigs` or `customConfigs[this.customType]` of being undefined

EDIT

Thanks for the playground, that highlights where the issue stands; Forget the above and simply have it as `customConfigs[this.customType].validate?()`

The question mark before the `validate` function, allow you to invoke the function only if the object beforehand exists

Comment: That's doesnt work, there is an error at the end waiting for a :

it thinks it's a ternary operation

Comment: Sorry, I might have explained wrongly; The question mark needs to go in the function invocation, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQFcBnGCAW3wiXQQHNi4BvAKDjgG0BrYATwC44pKMjoBdQa3bsAbpgA2CACaZUAfgAU6eZjqDMSXgEpBAIwgR5wAwG42cAL52HLFtmqk42EmUrVaDIJEpBRUNPSMALzMLBwA5KYGBsBxEjHScHKKKqgaxEbpGXBQwDCEUEhCdhkOADRsLi5uHvDeIeQAKrxgwPgAFhbEwJXRCUlIKa5tvmEBxPGJSMmpAHRZyqrAaisacfKWcUZ206H+ERwnnd29AxBDSGJrChvqO3sHR0A

Comment: that seems to work! 

how does the ?. work?? I never saw that before invoking a function

Comment: Glad it helped! That works the same way as question marks set before an object; All it does, is invoking the right side only if the left side is not `undefined`. You can use it with `obj?.property`, or `obj?.["property"]`, or `function?.()`

Comment: Thank you so much TIL that you can use the ? on a function. Have a good day

Comment: Thank you and no worries at all, always happy to help, have a great one too!